# Magento 1.7 - joined date column in grid

Tags: magento, magento-1.7

I need to have a grid showing the order items.

I use collection `sales/order_item_collection`

I join this with `sales/orders` to get the order date

```
$collection->getSelect()->join( 
           array('orders_alias' => $resource->getTableName('sales/order'))
           , 'main_table.order_id = orders_alias.entity_id'
           , array('orders_alias.increment_id', 'order_date' => 'orders_alias.created_at')
           , null);
```

Add column definition:

```
$this->addColumn('order_date',
        array(
            'header'=> $this->__('Date'),
            'align' =>'left',
            'width' => '100px',
            'index' => 'order_date',
            'type' => 'date'
        )
    );
```

I can see the date in the grid. See screenshot http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/252/scr027.jpg/

If I use the filter box and try to filter on a date I get this error:

```
SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'order_date' in 'where clause'
```

If I use this column index:

```
orders_alias.created_at
```

I get an empty column.

What do I need to change to use the filter on the date column?

---

### This solution from @KalpeshMehta works:

```
        $this->addColumn('order_date',
        array(
            'header'=> $this->__('Date'),
            'align' =>'left',
            'width' => '100px',
            'index' => 'order_date',
            'type' => 'date',
            'filter_index' => 'orders_alias.created_at'
        )
    );
```

Comment: to use filter, you should also use `filter_index` along with `index`.

Comment: I have often problems, when using getSelect()->join(). Instead you can use joinTable(), I blog about it last week: http://blog.fabian-blechschmidt.de/articles/Joining-a-flat-table-on-EAV.html

Comment: @KalpeshMehta Great, that works! If you put it in an answer I will accept :)

Comment: @Guus Glad to hear it solved. I have moved it as an answer :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@Guus, adding my comment as an answer, so that it can help others also facing the same problem.

To use filter, you should also use `filter_index` along with `index`.